# Spring unit test : Should I inject service for REST controller?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, unit-testing

I want to test my Spring boot controller, I have one question : if my controller uses some services, should I mock them or inject them ? In my opinion unit test for controllers should only test if controller is working well, not the underline services right ?

Comment: Is it a unit test or an integration test? Either way you must inject something either a mock of the service or the actual one. In case of a unit test you probably want to inject a mock.

Comment: If it’s integration test should I inject everything inside ?

Comment: mock for unit testing, real for integration testing. 
integration test is testing the interaction between compnents, so there, you have to set up the proper system  real components with some lightweight (embedded) db,queue etc... as you need)

Comment: For an integration test yes (but that is for **my definition** of an integration test).

Comment: Depends if you want to test the actual data returned by service or not. In many cases we only check to see if the method in service have been invoked with correct parameters. If you want to check if the JSOB returned by Controller's action have data according to your expected jsonPaths then you definitely need service injection via mocking.